# Is every $2$-generated simple group $\frac{3}{2}$-generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated, simple-groups

Let’s call a group $\frac{3}{2}$-generated iff for every $g \in G \setminus \{1\}$ there is some $h \in G \setminus \langle g \rangle$ with $G = \langle g,h \rangle$.

Is every $2$-generated simple group $\frac{3}{2}$-generated?

This happens to be true for finite simple groups and for Tarski monster groups, but is it true in general? I do not know how to prove that, but neither do I know any counterexamples.

Comment: Scott Harper, a recent PhD student in my department whose thesis made significant progress on 3/2-generation for finite groups (his nice poster https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~baumeist/wop2017/poster/Harper_poster.pdf has already been mentioned on MathOverflow), and who has also thought a bit about the problem for infinite groups, didn’t know the answer to this last time I asked him.

Comment: This question would better fit MO

Comment: @YCor Actually, I’d forgotten, but this question has already been asked on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324060/breuer-guralnick-kantor-conjecture-and-infinite-3-2-generated-groups